# How to take either multiple or single input on one line from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

To accept multiple inputs on one line, I know you can do something like:

```
a, b = input().split()
```

And if the user were to only type 1 input, they would come across a ValueError:

"ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Therefore is there a way of allowing the user the choice to write either 1 or both inputs so that if the user were to only have 1 input, the variable b would be forgotten or replaced with a placeholder?

Comment: `a = input().split()` & then `assert len(a) <= 2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, the best is probably to collect the list and act depending on its length.

Now, if you really want to handle at least 1, or 2 (or more), you could use packing/unpacking:

```
a, *b = input().split()

print(f'first variable is {a}')
print(f'there is {"a" if b else "no"} second variable')
if b:
    print(f'second variable is {b[0]}')
```

Example 1:

```
x y

first variable is x
there is a second variable
second variable is y
```

Example 2:

```
x

first variable is x
there is no second variable
```

##### default value:

```
a, *b = input().split()
b = next(iter(b), 'default')
print('variables:', a, b)
```

Example 1:

```
x y

variables: x y
```

Example 2:

```
x

variables: x default
```

Answer (score -1):

Take the input as a list
i.e.,

```py
lst = input().split()
```

So you won't get value error you can later make changes on the user input with the help of indexing ... lst[0]....

What is happening here:
`input()` is used to take the input and store it in the memory buffer before allocating to the variable
`split()` takes the value in the variable or input buffer and split it based on a white space
`input()` is similar to `input(" ")`
The above code can be also written as

````py
lst = input()
lst = lst.split()```
````

Comment: `input().split()` already outputs a list...

Comment: `str.split()` returns `list`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).